# Search <Img> tag from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have a variable that contain a `"text"` and `"<img>"` tag

I want to extract the `<img>` tag to get the `src` attribute, Can I do this with Javasript or Jquery ?

and, how to get the extracted text ?

Thanks for any response.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Show a sample of such variables

Comment: This is fairly easy, as @p4sh4 show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be as simple as

```
var var1 = "<img src='url'>";

alert($( var1 ).attr( "src" ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want somthing like this ?

```js
alert($("img").attr("src"))
alert($("img").attr("alt"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="this/is/the/url" alt="this is the text ?">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work in the straight forward way if the text is there before the `img` tag in the variable.. Try the following.

```js
var html = "dfffsdfsdf<span>M</span><img src='/sdfsdf/sfsdf/sdfdf.jpg'>";
var $dummy = $('<div></div>');
$dummy.append(html)
alert($dummy.find('img').first().attr( "src" )); //or use prop()
$dummy.empty();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```